# What is the recommended design pattern to avoid null pointer exceptions on references within a runnable when calling removeCallbacks()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-handler

Referencing the code below.  myRatingBar.setRating and myHandler.postDelayed within the runnable sporadically get a null pointer exception after calling stop().  I'm not sure what the best way to avoid this is.  The problem only worsens if the runnable contains objects with listeners and the listeners have references.

```
private Handler myHandler;
private Runnable myRunnable;
private RatingBar myRatingBar;

public void start()
{
    myRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            myRatingBar.setRating(1);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }

    myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 0);
}

public void stop()
{
    if(myHandler != null)
    {
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        myHandler = null;
    }

    myRunnable = null;
    myRatingBar = null;
}
```

Adding stacktrace.  In this stacktrace a ValueAnimator onAnimationUpdate was executing within the runnable.  The idea is the same overall.  Something is still executing in the runnable when stop() goes to set it to null.

08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183): Process: com.myprocess.myprocess, PID: 20183
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RatingBar.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at com.myprocess.myprocess.MyClass2$6$2.onAnimationUpdate(MyClass.java:487)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animateValue(ValueAnimator.java:1283)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1207)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1248)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:659)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:682)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
08-07 13:53:21.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by this code? It's hard to provide a solution since the problem is not defined.

Comment: Stacktrace added.  I'm trying to ensure references get null'd when stop happens to avoid holding memory.  Basically I need to ensure runnables are not executing still when I go setting null.  I assumed removeCallback would guarantee that but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to imagine there is a better way.  If someone has a better answer than what i'm doing to really "cover up" the problem, please enlighten me.  Here's what i'm shamefully doing for now.

```
private Handler myHandler;
private Runnable myRunnable;
private RatingBar myRatingBar;

public void start()
{
    myRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                myRatingBar.setRating(1);

                if(myHandler != null)
                {
                    myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }

    myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 0);
}

public void stop()
{
    if(myHandler != null)
    {
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        myHandler = null;
    }

    myRunnable = null;
    myRatingBar = null;
}
```